# problem with customlist view?

Tags: android, android-layout

below is my code for customlist.

```
package com.demo.list;

import java.util.ArrayList;



import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyCustomListView extends ListActivity {
    private ArrayList<String> m_orders=null;
    private OrderAdapter m_adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        m_orders = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            m_orders.add("Android List");
        }
        this.m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, R.layout.row, m_orders);
                setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);
    }
    private class OrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private ArrayList<String> items;
        public OrderAdapter(Context context,int id,ArrayList<String> items)
        {
            super();
            this.items=items;
        }

        public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view=convertView;
            if(view==null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
            }
            String string=items.get(position);
            if(string!=null)
            {
                TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                TextView t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
                ImageView imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
                if(t1!=null)
                {
                    t1.setText("Name:-"+string.toString());
                }
                if(t2!=null)
                {
                    t2.setText("Status:-"+string.toString());
                }
            if(imageview!=null)
                {
                    imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
                }
            }
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 10;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginRight="6dip">
    </ImageView>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/toptext"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="0dip"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="0dip"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:singleLine="true"
                  android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout
```

My problem is that i am only getting first element of the list though i have added 10 elements to arraylist.
can anyone tell me what is the wrong with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace:

```
view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
```

With:

```
view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
```

Edit:

Also, replace:

```
TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.toptext);
TextView t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
ImageView imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
```

With:

```
TextView t1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
TextView t2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
ImageView imageview=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
```

Btw: most of your adapter is coded incorrectly. I'm assuming this is because you're just trying to quickly see this working.

Comment: i treid this but with this i am getting only five elements from 10.

Comment: is there anyways that i can improve it.

Comment: thankx                                                               can you tell me how can i improve my adapter implemetation.

Comment: view.findview.... solves my problem  but again i am saying that can u pls tell me how can i improve my adapter.